# Is infinite linear combination of concave function still concave

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f_n(x)$ be  concave functions.

I know that 
\begin{align}
g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N a_nf_n(x)
\end{align}
where $a_n  \ge 0$ and $N<\infty$ is concave.

My question is if the sum becomes infinite sume is $g(x)$ still concave? 
To me it seems yes, since in the proof we do not assume anyting about finitness of the sum:

\begin{align}
g((1-t)x+ty)&=\sum a_nf_n((1-t)x+ty) \ge  \sum a_n ( (1-t)f_n(x)+tf_n(y))\\
&=(1-t) g(x)+tg(y)
\end{align}

Comment: In last step, to "split" the sum, you must assume that $f_n$ pointwise coverges absolutely.

Comment: @ajotatxe you mean the sum of the $f_n$?

Comment: @ajotatxe I don't see why the series should converge absolutely. We just need that $\sum a_nf_n$ converges (simply) pointwise.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge so does $\sum a_n + b_n$. The reverse statement is not true. (So if you can read if from right to left it's ok).

Comment: @Thomas Precisely: Since the convergence is pointwise, $\sum a_nf_n(x)$ converges, and so does $\sum a_n(1-t)f_n(x)$, and also $\sum a_n f_n(y)$ converges, and so does $\sum a_n tf_n(y)$. Now apply the result as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may or may not have guessed from the comments, if you know that the sum converges (pointwise) for every argument you want to check it for (that is, in this case, for $(1-t)x+ty, (1-t)x$, and $ty$ then the conclusion is valid.

The proof of the inequality would usually be done by reducing it to a finite sum and some $\varepsilon, \delta $ logic, but it's rather straightforward.